# The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application, flutter2.0, flutter-exception

After running the Flutter project, I get this error. What can I do to solve it?

```
Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' 
isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I had the same problem after update plugin's in AndroidStudio on Mac

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

did nothing for me, but

```
flutter clean
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

has solved the problem

Comment: I dont want to update all my dependencies. How can I identifiy the specific dependecy which I need to upgrade?

Comment: Lifesaver! Thanks :D

Comment: This didn't work for me on Mac. Any steps specific to Mac?

Comment: flutter pub upgrade --major-versions 
It's working fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to specified class 'BasicMessageChannel' by press and hold ctrl and click on it
2. than search for the 'setMockMessageHandler' by ctrl+F
   than u will see something like this
   // Looking for setMockMessageHandler?
   // See this shim package: packages/flutter_test/lib/src/deprecated.dart
   and paste this line below this comment
   void setMockMessageHandler(dynamic message){

}
but this is just simple hack which is not recommended

Comment: best thing to do when legacy need some hotfix

Answer (score 4):

Running across this problem after upgrading to Flutter 2.5.3 (from 2.2.3). The change outlined in the [release notes](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/mock-platform-channels) broke several hundred tests since the mock method handlers were set in the global `setUp()` for most tests.

As shown in the release notes, I replaced code like

```
 MethodChannel('channelName')
   .setMockMethodCallHandler((MethodCall methodCall) {});
```

with code using the default instance of `TestDefaultBinaryMessenger`:

```
 TestDefaultBinaryMessengerBinding.instance.defaultBinaryMessenger
   .setMockMethodCallHandler(MethodChannel('channelName'), (MethodCall methodCall) {});
```

This change allowed me to keep all tests unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today.

from what i could notice, this basically was a breaking change caused by transition of platform channel test interfaces to flutter_test package.

in my case, the problem was resolved just running the `flutter pub upgrade` on a global terminal session.

see more details about the mentioned transition on [referred release notes](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/mock-platform-channels)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, I have tried all the above and did not help.
`flutter pub upgrade` and `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions` outputs this:

No dependencies changed.

1 package is discontinued.

76 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.

Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.

No changes to pubspec.yaml!
The plugins `advance_pdf_viewer, flutter_absolute_path, geocoder, google_api_headers, onesignal_flutter` use a deprecated version of the
Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if these plugins support the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise,
consider removing them since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding:
https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: I have the same problem, only explained what i did, still not working

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1

1. : flutter pub upgrade
2. : flutter clean
3. : flutter pub upgrade
   --major-versions
4. : cd ios
5. : pod repo update
6. : pod update
7. : open Runner.xcworkspace
8. : make clean & make run