# setMockMessageHandler'.channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

I wanted to add dependences in my flutter project for that I need to update to new flutter version. While updating I am getting above error.

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:432:15: Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart' ('../../../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setMockMessageHandler'.
      channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Refer the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67915153/the-method-setmockmessagehandler-isnt-defined-for-the-class-basicmessagechan

Comment: I have followed those commands, but I am unable to add new dependencies without upgrading, when I upgrade that it shows exit 0, when I try to run the code in my phone it was again showing the same error. I am using flutter 2.5.2, When I use flutter 2.2.2 my code runs in it, but I am unable to add new dependencies without flutter upgrading.

Comment: @KiranmayiJagan have you found the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try to do

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

if this does not work try

```
flutter clean
```

then

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

The above two commands should solve the errors but still suppose this **--major-version** commands gives you this error packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints then try

```
flutter pub outdated
```

and after this still, it not working then upgrade your kotlin version in android/build.gradle

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.10'
```

and minsdk and compilesdk version to the latest.